# How can I bind a proxy, check if it works and determine its location in Selenium (Chrome)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, proxy

**Edit: I solved the last two problems myself by using bypass solutions. Very important is still the first problem, how to add the proxies in the first place.**

I just wrote a short code that allows Selenium in Python to open a Chrome browser and select a random user agent.
It's not supposed to be about user agents, but about proxies. I have a text file (in the format `URL:PORT:USERNAME:PASSWORD`) stored locally, and I want Python to check them to see if they work (and if possible specify which country they are from) before using them.

I can do this manually myself with a second Python program if necessary, or if possible I want Python to check that the proxies work before using them. Python should then save the working proxies in a separate text file (e.g. `working proxies.txt`). These working proxies shall be used by Python to call e.g. "google.com". However, it should select the proxies from the list in order. So when the process is finished, it is supposed to take the next line of proxies in the next process.

I hope someone can help me to include the proxies and run the above commands. I'm really getting desperate and unfortunately can't get any further here.
Of course, I can post the code I've written so far, but I don't think it will do anything because it just opens a page with a random user agent.

Comment: Nobody? Is this question so complex?

Comment: I solved the last two problems myself by using bypass solutions. Very important is still the first problem, how to add the proxies in the first place.